# Кодировка: UTF8 -> ANSI

Tags: c#, перекодировка

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой: есть файл в ANSI кодировке и я его считываю построчно, но насколько я правильно понял, в C# эта считанная строка хранится в юникоде и в ней я наблюдаю какие-то иероглифы. Что делаю я (на примере 1-ой строчки файла):

```
StreamReader read = new StreamReader(@"D:\(path)");

StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter(@"D:\(path)");

Encoding ANSI = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
Encoding UTF8 = Encoding.UTF8;
byte[] utf8_bytes,ansi_bytes;

utf8_bytes = UTF8.GetBytes(read.ReadLine());
ansi_bytes = Encoding.Convert(UTF8, ANSI, utf8_bytes);

string ansi_str = ANSI.GetString(ansi_bytes);

write.WriteLine(ansi_str);

read.Close();
write.Close();
```

Но это почему-то не работает: в новом файле все также отображается много непонятных вопросительных знаков. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Кстати в самом конструкторе StreamReader\StreamWriter можно выставлять кодировку и тогда все будет намного легче , но мне бы хотелось разобраться почему не работает моим способом .

Comment: - покажите кусочек текста входного файла. Есть подозрение что он на кириллице (win-1251), а вы манипулируете с помощью 1252 (в ней кракозяблики на месте русских букв)
 - какая конечная цель данных манипуляций?

Comment: 1)Да,перепутал,там 1251 у ANSI, но так тоже не работает
Encoding ANSI = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).Сам файл это словарь русских слов в кодировке ANSI (по крайней мере просто в Notepad++ она выставлена)
2)Конечная цель - есть словарь синонимов (~20k слов) и из каждой строчки я убираю определения самих терминов , оставляя  только сами слова .

Comment: У меня просто такое ощущение что, когда идет запись в файл , то он автоматом опять в юникод преобразуется

Answer (score 4):

Посмотрите внимательнее на код:

1. прочитать текст, записанный в файле в UTF-8 (по умолчанию для StreamReader)
2. записать текст в UTF-16LE строке (класс System.String в .NET)
3. получить представление текста в кодировке UTF-8 в виде массива байтов
4. преобразовать текст из UTF-8 в ANSI, получая массив байтов
5. преобразовать текст из кодировки ANSI в UTF-16LE для записи в System.String
6. записать текст (который сейчас в System.String), используя StreamWriter (который по умолчанию пишет в кодировке UTF-8)

Итого получается, что текст проходит следующие преобразования:

UTF-8 (StreamReader) -> UTF-16LE (System.String) -> UTF-8 (byte[]) -> ANSI (byte[]) -> UTF-16LE (System.String) -> UTF-8 (StreamWriter)

Думаю, что теперь стало очевидно, в чём проблема.

Comment: Ага,ясно,спасибо.Единственное а как же я массив байтов в ANSI преобразую в строку именно с соответствующей кодировкой, а не  UTF-16LE ? То есть насколько я правильно понял в моем примере в строке ansi_str будет строка в UTF-16LE .

Comment: Строка System.String в .NET *всегда* в кодировке UFT-16LE; метод `Encoding.GetString()` выполняет данную конвертацию.

Comment: Что-то я уже ничего не понимаю : если System.String в .NET всегда в кодировке UFT-16LE , а Encoding.GetString() возвращает System.String.
Тогда сразу надо писать массив байтов в этот поток как-то ?

Comment: Да, именно так. Создавайте поток для записи в файл ([`FileStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.filestream.aspx)) и используйте метод [`Stream.Write()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.stream.write.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
StreamReader read = new StreamReader(@"D:\(path)");

StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter(@"D:\(path)");

Encoding ANSI = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251);
Encoding UTF8 = Encoding.UTF8;
byte[] utf8_bytes,ansi_bytes;

utf8_bytes = UTF8.GetBytes(read.ReadLine());
ansi_bytes = Encoding.Convert(UTF8, ANSI, utf8_bytes);

string ansi_str = ANSI.GetString(ansi_bytes);

write.WriteLine(ansi_str);

read.Close();
write.Close();
```

Попробуйте 1251 вместо 1252, тогда русские символы будут отображаться корректно.